# angularjs functions ($http, $location, ...) are not working

Tags: angularjs, http

I have a simple angularjs application and I would like to make http request, but I really don't know why it is not working. Here is my controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

        /**
        * @ngdoc function
        * @name app.controller:HomeCtrl
        * @description
        * # HomeCtrl
        * Controller of the app
        */

      angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard')
      .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location', HomeCtrl ]);
        function HomeCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
          $scope.samples = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']];

        console.log($http);
        console.log($scope);
        console.log($location);
        console.log(window.location.hostname);
        $http.get(
          'http://localhost' +   ':7000/samples', 

          {}
        ).then(function(err, data){
          if (err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
        },
        function(err, data){
        });

            var varApplist = this;
        }
    })();
```

I my patial homeCtrl:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
......
<div>
```

in my index.html

when I try to run, I am having this error:

```
TypeError: $http.get is not a function
    at new HomeCtrl (http://localhost:4001/app/pages/dashboard/home/homeCtrl.js:21:11)
    at invoke (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4570:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4578:27)
    at http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9460:28
    at http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4081:28
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9099:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8586:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7975:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7855:30)
    at updateView (http://localhost:4001/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4021:23) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

when I log $location and $http, I have and empty object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location', HomeCtrl ]);
        function HomeCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
```

Except for `$scope`, the actual parameters of your function don't match, at all, with the dependencies declared at the beginning of the array.

Do yourself a favor, and stop using this ugly and bug-prone array notation. Use ng-annotate to make your code minifiable automatically.

Also note that the callback passed to `then()` will be called with a single argument. So the `data` argument you have there is useless.

Answer (score 1):

need to match your dependency injection sequence with the string values

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location',
            function HomeCtrl($scope, $rootScope,$stateParams, $http, $location) {
```

When you are initializing the angular module, need to add empty squire brackets for the module injection

`angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard',[])`

also remove `err` in your promise `(then)`

```
.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // success response
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data); // error resoponse
    });
```

full controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

      angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard',[])
      .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$location',
        function HomeCtrl($scope, $rootScope,$stateParams, $http, $location) {
          $scope.samples = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']];

        console.log($http);
        console.log($scope);
        console.log($location);
        console.log(window.location.hostname);
        $http.get(
          'http://localhost' +   ':7000/samples', 

          {}
        ).then(function(data){

          console.log(data);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

            var varApplist = this;
    }])


    })();
```